# How do I fix a bad operand error in Java?

Tags: java

I keep getting this error in my code for this line: error: bad operand types for binary operator '<='

Code: `if (FIRST_YEAR <= year <= LAST_YEAR || 1 <= month <= 12 || 1 <= day <= 31)`

Comment: That's not how comparison works in Java (or any language of the C family tree). Try e.g. `FIRST_YEAR <= year && year <= LAST_YEAR` instead.

Comment: your using pure math notation in Java, but clearly you should use what Java allows ... comparison operands are a binary relation in Java

Answer (score 2):

Because of the associativity of the comparison operators

```
FIRST_YEAR <= year <= LAST_YEAR
```

is the same as

```
(FIRST_YEAR <= year) <= LAST_YEAR
```

i.e. you are try to compare `FIRST_YEAR` to `year`, and then compare the result of that to `LAST_YEAR`.

The result of the first comparison is a boolean: is it less than or equal to, or not.

So, a boolean is then being compared to a number of some kind. The language spec [explicitly requires](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.20.1) that both operands are convertible to  numeric types; as boolean is not so convertible, this is a compiler error.

You have to do two separate comparisons, and AND them together:

```
(FIRST_YEAR <= year) // a boolean
  &&                 // an operator taking 2 boolean operands
(year <= LAST_YEAR)  // a boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` like `if ((FIRST_YEAR <= year && year<= LAST_YEAR) || .......)`

Answer (score 0):

For operations, it is important to include brackets similar to using brackets with operations in math:

if (FIRST_YEAR <= year && year <= LAST_YEAR) || (1 <= month && month <= 12) || (1 <= day && day <= 31)

You need to include the variable whenever assigning operands, and each condition must be in brackets in order for java to read it correctly. With your code java isn't aware that you are assigning <= LAST_YEAR to 'year' and doesn't know which variable to assign the logical operator to.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest break your logic example

```
Boolean check = false;

//step 1 logic: year check for first and last year
if(FIRST_YEAR=< Year && Year <=LAST_Year)
check = TRUE;

// if step 1 is true now step 2: month is between 1 and 2:
if(month =>1 and month <=12)
check = check && TRUE;
```

This way you can debug easily and more manageable code. Also you will certainly need to display errors like here you want to accept or reject a date given by user or system, you will definitely want to display the issue e.g. month entered is incorrect or year is unacceptable etc...